# How to get the value of radio and text field in to single text area

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of the Radio button and input field into single Text area field

I already tried to search for some code on several website but I can not get it to work

```js
document.mainForm.onclick = function() {
  var gender = document.querySelector('input[name = gender]:checked').value;
  result.innerHTML = 'Dear ' + gender;

}

function myInput() {
  var y = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = y;
}
```

```html
<p>Select Email templates below</p>
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr." />Mr.
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mrs." />Mrs.
</form>
<br>
<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="please input your texts here" oninput="myInput()" /></textarea>

Real time generated email template
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="result" name="text"></textarea>
```

Select Radio button + User input field on text area then output will be

Selected Radio button + User input field
example: Mr. Stackover

But when I select the radio button it goes to output text area then when I entered a text on text area field it deleted the radio button and create a new text

By the way I am new in web dev. Please no jargon.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `+=` to retain the previous text of the element.

Change

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = y;
```

To

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += y;
```

Also, I will suggest you to use `textContent` or `innerText` if the text does not contain any HTML.

```js
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=gender]');
radios.forEach(function(r){
  r.addEventListener('change', function(){
    var gender = document.querySelector('input[name = gender]:checked').value;
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = 'Dear '+ gender;
  });
});


function myInput(){
  var y = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
  document.getElementById('result').textContent += y;  
}
```

```html
<p>Select Email templates below</p>
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr."/>Mr.
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mrs." />Mrs.
</form>
<br>

<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="please input your texts here" oninput="myInput()"/></textarea>

Real time generated email template
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="result" name="text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can assign value in variable and later use as below.**

```js
var static_label = '';
document.mainForm.onclick = function(){
    var gender = document.querySelector('input[name = gender]:checked').value;
    static_label = 'Dear '+gender;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = static_label;  

}

function myInput(){
var y = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = static_label + y;  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Select Email templates below</p>
    <form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr." />Mr.
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mrs." />Mrs.
</form>
<br>

<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="please input your texts here" oninput="myInput()"/></textarea>

Real time generated email template
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="result" name="text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code work for you

```js
document.mainForm.onclick = function(){
  renderYourText()
}

function renderYourText(){
  var gender = document.querySelector('input[name = gender]:checked').value;
  var y = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML ='Dear '+gender + y; 
}
```

```html
<p>Select Email templates below</p>
  <form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr." />Mr.
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mrs." />Mrs.
  </form>
<br>

<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="please input your texts here" oninput="renderYourText()"></textarea>

Real time generated email template
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="result" name="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: This one work! Thank you very much you save my time doing research hehehe :)